# Loading a png in opentk does not work as expected

Tags: opengl, png, opentk

I'm trying to load a PNG with OpenGL (via OpenTK) and the Image is extremely pixelated and has the wrong color.

The code:

```
private void Create(SurfaceFormat format)
        {
            textureHandle = (uint)GL.GenTexture();
            //bind texture
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, textureHandle);
            Log.Error("Bound Texture: " + GL.GetError());
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Nearest);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)format.WrapMode);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)format.WrapMode);
            Log.Error("Created Texture Parameters: " + GL.GetError());
            GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, format.InternalFormat, Width, Height, 0, format.PixelFormat, format.SourceType, format.Pixels);
            Log.Error("Created Image: " + GL.GetError());
            //unbind texture
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0);

            //create fbo
            fboHandle = (uint)GL.GenFramebuffer();
            GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, fboHandle);
            GL.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0Ext, TextureTarget.Texture2D, textureHandle, 0);
            GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, 0);
            Log.Error("Created Framebuffer: " + GL.GetError());
        }
        public void CreateFromPNG(string filePath)
        {
            //check if the file exists
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                //make a bitmap out of the file on the disk
                System.Drawing.Bitmap textureBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(filePath);
                //get the data out of the bitmap
                System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData textureData =
                textureBitmap.LockBits(
                        new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, textureBitmap.Width, textureBitmap.Height),
                        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb
                    );
                if(textureBitmap.PixelFormat != System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
                {
                    Log.Error("PNG Pixel format not supported ("+ filePath +") -> " + textureBitmap.PixelFormat.ToString());
                    return;
                }
                SurfaceFormat format = new SurfaceFormat();
                format.Pixels = textureData.Scan0;
                format.SourceType = PixelType.Byte;
                Create(format);
                //free the bitmap data (we dont need it anymore because it has been passed to the OpenGL driver
                textureBitmap.UnlockBits(textureData);

            }
        }
```

[image: Result when rendering]

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT: I fixed the colors via**

```
format.SourceType = PixelType.UnsignedByte;
format.PixelFormat = PixelFormat.Bgra;
```

**EDIT2: Fixed it**. Apparently pngs with transparency get distorted when blending is not correctly enabled!

```
GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
```

But the distortion is still going on

Comment: if you need a quick fix, use jpg instead of png, gdi format argb, opengl format bgra...working well...

Answer (score 0):

The distortion might be related to what is described [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417946/sprite-texture-atlas-gdi-bitmap-maketransparent-for-color-key-with-opentk?rq=1).

Try using `System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb` to see if it makes a difference.